# Dynamically binding to nested object property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to bind to a property of a nested object with [(ngModel)], but the problem is that the "path" to property is dynamically set.

Let's say we have three classes like so:

```typescript
class A {
 p1: C
 constructor() {
  p1 = new C("A")
 }
}
class B {
 p2: C
 constructor() {
  p2 = new C("B")
 }
}
class C {
 constructor(public id: string){}
}
```

**reusable.component.html** like this:

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="data[propName]">
```

**reusable.component.ts** like this:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: "app-reusable[data][nestedProperty]",
  templateUrl: "./reusable.component.html"
})
export class ReusableComponent<T> {
 @Input()
 nestedProperty!: string
 @Input()
 data!: T
}
```

and **app.component.html** like so:

```html
<app-reusable [data]="d1" [nestedProperty]="s1"></app-reusable>
<app-reusable [data]="d2" [nestedProperty]="s2"></app-reusable>
```

and **app.component.ts** like so:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
d1 = new A()
d2 = new B()
s1 = "p1.id"
s2 = "p2.id"
}
```

my logic for this kind of approach was that `d1.p1` gets the same value as `d1["p1"]`, but i found out that `d1["p1.id"]` does't get the same value as `d1.p1.id`

**Is there any kind of workaround that would enable me to fetch a nested object value using only string path to the nested object?**

My workaround was to create property `d1["p1.id"]` inside the constructor and assign it `d1.p1.id` value like so:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
d1 = new A()
d2 = new B()
s1 = "p1.id"
s2 = "p2.id"

 constructor() {
  this.d1[s1] = this.d1.p1.id
  this.d2[s2] = this.d2.p2.id
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the path to get the property You can use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to evaluate the expression to access it:

> The eval() function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string

If you have an object as

```
var myObject = {
   innerObject: {
      nestedProperty: 'The value'
   }
};
```

You can get the string 'The value' doing

```
var nestedValue = eval("myObject.innerObject.nestedProperty");
// Here nestedValue has the value 'The value'
```

Note that the use of eval can be dangerous because it will execute any kind of string as it is a code, so a better way to solve the problem in this case is to use the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

```
function extractProperty(path) {
   return Function('"use strict";return (' + path + ')')();
}
```

and use it as follow for the previous example:

```
var nestedValue = extractProperty("myObject.innerObject.nestedProperty");
```

This is a standard javascript code, but you can adapt it to your typescript needs.

Comment: Actually, I would like to get the reference to 'nestedProperty' because I will need to change that value inside the object.

Comment: If you use the extractProperty to get the object holding the value instead of the value itself you can change it as follow: extractProperty("myObject.innerObject").nestedProperty = "newValue";